# Split Spark dataframe string column into multiple columns

Tags: string, apache-spark, pyspark, split, apache-spark-sql

I've seen various people suggesting that `Dataframe.explode` is a useful way to do this, but it results in more rows than the original dataframe, which isn't what I want at all. I simply want to do the Dataframe equivalent of the very simple:

```py
rdd.map(lambda row: row + [row.my_str_col.split('-')])
```

which takes something looking like:

```
col1 | my_str_col
-----+-----------
  18 |  856-yygrm
 201 |  777-psgdg
```

and converts it to this:

```
col1 | my_str_col | _col3 | _col4
-----+------------+-------+------
  18 |  856-yygrm |   856 | yygrm
 201 |  777-psgdg |   777 | psgdg
```

I am aware of `pyspark.sql.functions.split()`, but it results in a nested array column instead of two top-level columns like I want.

Ideally, I want these new columns to be named as well.

Answer (score 171):

`pyspark.sql.functions.split()` is the right approach here - you simply need to flatten the nested ArrayType column into multiple top-level columns. In this case, where each array only contains 2 items, it's very easy. You simply use `Column.getItem()` to retrieve each part of the array as a column itself:

```
split_col = pyspark.sql.functions.split(df['my_str_col'], '-')
df = df.withColumn('NAME1', split_col.getItem(0))
df = df.withColumn('NAME2', split_col.getItem(1))
```

The result will be:

```
col1 | my_str_col | NAME1 | NAME2
-----+------------+-------+------
  18 |  856-yygrm |   856 | yygrm
 201 |  777-psgdg |   777 | psgdg
```

I am not sure how I would solve this in a general case where the nested arrays were not the same size from Row to Row.

Comment: Is there a way to put the remaining items in a single column? i.e. 
    `split_col.getItem(2 - n)` in a third column. I guess something like the above loop to make columns for all items then concatenating them might work, but I don't know if that's very efficient or not.

Comment: Use df.withColumn('NAME_remaining', pyspark.sql.functions.split(df[my_str_col'],'-',3).getItem(2) to get the remaining items. https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html

Comment: I found that if you are trying to assign one of the split items back to the original column, you have to rename the original column with withColumnRenamed() before the split in order to avoid an error apparently related to https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-14948.

Comment: How do you perform a split such that first part of the split is columnname and the second part is the column value?

Answer (score 57):

Here's a solution to the general case that doesn't involve needing to know the length of the array ahead of time, using `collect`, or using `udf`s. Unfortunately this only works for `spark` version 2.1 and above, because it requires the [`posexplode`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.posexplode) function.

Suppose you had the following DataFrame:

```python
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        [1, 'A, B, C, D'], 
        [2, 'E, F, G'], 
        [3, 'H, I'], 
        [4, 'J']
    ]
    , ["num", "letters"]
)
df.show()
#+---+----------+
#|num|   letters|
#+---+----------+
#|  1|A, B, C, D|
#|  2|   E, F, G|
#|  3|      H, I|
#|  4|         J|
#+---+----------+
```

Split the `letters` column and then use `posexplode` to explode the resultant array along with the position in the array. Next use `pyspark.sql.functions.expr` to grab the element at index `pos` in this array.

```python
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

df.select(
        "num",
        f.split("letters", ", ").alias("letters"),
        f.posexplode(f.split("letters", ", ")).alias("pos", "val")
    )\
    .show()
#+---+------------+---+---+
#|num|     letters|pos|val|
#+---+------------+---+---+
#|  1|[A, B, C, D]|  0|  A|
#|  1|[A, B, C, D]|  1|  B|
#|  1|[A, B, C, D]|  2|  C|
#|  1|[A, B, C, D]|  3|  D|
#|  2|   [E, F, G]|  0|  E|
#|  2|   [E, F, G]|  1|  F|
#|  2|   [E, F, G]|  2|  G|
#|  3|      [H, I]|  0|  H|
#|  3|      [H, I]|  1|  I|
#|  4|         [J]|  0|  J|
#+---+------------+---+---+
```

Now we create two new columns from this result. First one is the name of our new column, which will be a concatenation of `letter` and the index in the array. The second column will be the value at the corresponding index in the array. We get the latter by exploiting the functionality of `pyspark.sql.functions.expr` which allows us [use column values as parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51140470/using-a-column-value-as-a-parameter-to-a-spark-dataframe-function).

```python
df.select(
        "num",
        f.split("letters", ", ").alias("letters"),
        f.posexplode(f.split("letters", ", ")).alias("pos", "val")
    )\
    .drop("val")\
    .select(
        "num",
        f.concat(f.lit("letter"),f.col("pos").cast("string")).alias("name"),
        f.expr("letters[pos]").alias("val")
    )\
    .show()
#+---+-------+---+
#|num|   name|val|
#+---+-------+---+
#|  1|letter0|  A|
#|  1|letter1|  B|
#|  1|letter2|  C|
#|  1|letter3|  D|
#|  2|letter0|  E|
#|  2|letter1|  F|
#|  2|letter2|  G|
#|  3|letter0|  H|
#|  3|letter1|  I|
#|  4|letter0|  J|
#+---+-------+---+
```

Now we can just `groupBy` the `num` and `pivot` the DataFrame. Putting that all together, we get:

```python
df.select(
        "num",
        f.split("letters", ", ").alias("letters"),
        f.posexplode(f.split("letters", ", ")).alias("pos", "val")
    )\
    .drop("val")\
    .select(
        "num",
        f.concat(f.lit("letter"),f.col("pos").cast("string")).alias("name"),
        f.expr("letters[pos]").alias("val")
    )\
    .groupBy("num").pivot("name").agg(f.first("val"))\
    .show()
#+---+-------+-------+-------+-------+
#|num|letter0|letter1|letter2|letter3|
#+---+-------+-------+-------+-------+
#|  1|      A|      B|      C|      D|
#|  3|      H|      I|   null|   null|
#|  2|      E|      F|      G|   null|
#|  4|      J|   null|   null|   null|
#+---+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

Comment: FYI I tried this with 3909 elements to split on ~1.7M original rows and it was too slow / not completing after an hour

Answer (score 21):

Here's another approach, in case you want split a string with a delimiter.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

df = spark.createDataFrame([("1:a:2001",),("2:b:2002",),("3:c:2003",)],["value"])
df.show()
+--------+
|   value|
+--------+
|1:a:2001|
|2:b:2002|
|3:c:2003|
+--------+

df_split = df.select(f.split(df.value,":")).rdd.flatMap(
              lambda x: x).toDF(schema=["col1","col2","col3"])

df_split.show()
+----+----+----+
|col1|col2|col3|
+----+----+----+
|   1|   a|2001|
|   2|   b|2002|
|   3|   c|2003|
+----+----+----+
```

I don't think this transition back and forth to RDDs is going to slow you down...
Also don't worry about last schema specification: it's optional, you can avoid it generalizing the solution to data with unknown column size.

Comment: how can I do this in scala? I get stuck with the flatMap lambda function

Comment: pay attention the pattern is given as a regular expression, hence you need to use \ for special characters

Comment: If you don't want to refer back to `df` inside your expression, you can pass the name of the column to `split`, i.e. `df.select(f.split("value",":"))...`

Comment: @moshebeeri You saved me!

Comment: What if there were more than one column ("value")? How would `flatMap` behave in this case?

Comment: @JoyfulPanda Usually, when Spark cannot univocally identify a column this error is raised: `pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: Reference 'value' is ambiguous, could be: value, value.`

Answer (score 2):

I understand your pain. Using split() can work, but can also lead to breaks.

Let's take your df and make a slight change to it:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([('1:"a:3":2001',),('2:"b":2002',),('3:"c":2003',)],["value"]) 

df.show()

+------------+
|       value|
+------------+
|1:"a:3":2001|
|  2:"b":2002|
|  3:"c":2003|
+------------+
```

If you try to apply split() to this as outlined above:

```
df_split = df.select(split(df.value,":")).rdd.flatMap(
              lambda x: x).toDF(schema=["col1","col2","col3"]).show()
```

you will get

> IllegalStateException: Input row doesn't have expected number of values required by the schema. 4 fields are required while 3 values are provided.

So, is there a more elegant way of addressing this? I was so happy to have it pointed out to me. [pyspark.sql.functions.from_csv()](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.from_csv.html) is your friend.

Taking my above example df:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import from_csv

# Define a column schema to apply with from_csv()
col_schema = ["col1 INTEGER","col2 STRING","col3 INTEGER"]
schema_str = ",".join(col_schema)

# define the separator because it isn't a ','
options = {'sep': ":"}

# create a df from the value column using schema and options
df_csv = df.select(from_csv(df.value, schema_str, options).alias("value_parsed"))
df_csv.show()

+--------------+
|  value_parsed|
+--------------+
|[1, a:3, 2001]|
|  [2, b, 2002]|
|  [3, c, 2003]|
+--------------+
```

Then we can easily flatten the df to put the values in columns:

```
df2 = df_csv.select("value_parsed.*").toDF("col1","col2","col3")
df2.show()

+----+----+----+
|col1|col2|col3|
+----+----+----+
|   1| a:3|2001|
|   2|   b|2002|
|   3|   c|2003|
+----+----+----+
```

No breaks. Data correctly parsed. Life is good. Have a beer.

Comment: Using this regex in split() method should also do the trick- [:](?=(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `Column.getItem(i)` we can use `Column[i]`.
Also, `enumerate` is useful in big dataframes.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
```

- **Keep parent column:**

  ```py
  for i, c in enumerate(['new_1', 'new_2']):
      df = df.withColumn(c, F.split('my_str_col', '-')[i])
  ```

  or

  ```py
  new_cols = ['new_1', 'new_2']
  df = df.select('*', *[F.split('my_str_col', '-')[i].alias(c) for i, c in enumerate(new_cols)])
  ```
- **Replace parent column:**

  ```py
  for i, c in enumerate(['new_1', 'new_2']):
      df = df.withColumn(c, F.split('my_str_col', '-')[i])
  df = df.drop('my_str_col')
  ```

  or

  ```py
  new_cols = ['new_1', 'new_2']
  df = df.select(
      *[c for c in df.columns if c != 'my_str_col'],
      *[F.split('my_str_col', '-')[i].alias(c) for i, c in enumerate(new_cols)]
  )
  ```