# Stemming each sentence, of each row of Spark dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a spark dataframe and I want to process each sentence(lower, remove punctuation) of each line.

To be more specific:

```
|text                            |
+--------------------------------+
|  This is a text.I want to split!
+---------------------------------
```

And I want to get this dataframe:

```
|text                            |
+---------------------------------
| [this is text ][i want to split]
+---------------------------------
```

Comment: Do you have an example code of your attempt ?

Comment: `SplitSentences = df.withColumn("split_sent",sentencesplit_udf(col('Text')))
SplitSentences = SplitSentences.select(SplitSentences.split_sent)`  where `sentencesplit_udf = udf(lambda x: splitSentences(x))` also i have created a function `def clean(text)`   If create a udf of this and try to combine it with udf of split it doesn't work

Comment: With the function clean I remove stopwords, lower() etc. So I want to "clean" each splitted sentence

Comment: Have you seen this solution in SO already ? [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39235704/split-spark-dataframe-string-column-into-multiple-columns)

Comment: Also next time it’s best to post the example code in the question not as a comment as it’s difficult to read.

Comment: Yes you are right about that. And I apologize for this. Well, I haven't seen this and it worked. Thank you very much

Comment: No problem. Glad it worked :)