# pyspark Regexp_Extract - Extract multiple words from a string column

Tags: pyspark

I am trying to extract words from a strings column using pyspark regexp.

**My DataFrame Below :**

```
ID, Code

10, A1005*B1003

12, A1007*D1008*C1004

result=df.withColumn('Code1', regexp_extract(col(Code), '\w+',0))
```

**Output :**

```
ID, Code,              Code1, 

10, A1005*B1003,       A1005

12, A1007*D1008*C1004, A1007

result=df.withColumn('Code1', regexp_extract(col(Code), '\w+',0))
```

**Output :**

```
ID, Code,              Code1, 

10, A1005*B1003,       A1005

12, A1007*D1008*C1004, A1007
```

I want to extract codes from Code column and i want my DataFrame to display as below.

```
ID, Code,              Code1,  Code2,  Code3

10, A1005*B1003,       A1005,  B1003,  null

12, A1007*D1008*C1004, A1007,  D1008,  C1004
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Split Spark Dataframe string column into multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39235704/split-spark-dataframe-string-column-into-multiple-columns)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume your `ID` column is unique for each row; Here is one way of doing it with `split`, `explode` and then `pivot`:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

(df.select('ID', 'Code', f.posexplode(f.split('Code', '\\*')))
   .withColumn('pos', f.concat(f.lit('code'), f.col('pos')))
   .groupBy('ID', 'Code').pivot('pos').agg(f.first('col'))
   .show())
+---+-----------------+-----+-----+-----+
| ID|             Code|code0|code1|code2|
+---+-----------------+-----+-----+-----+
| 10|      A1005*B1003|A1005|B1003| null|
| 12|A1007*D1008*C1004|A1007|D1008|C1004|
+---+-----------------+-----+-----+-----+
```

Another option without pivoting:

```py
df1 = df.select('ID', 'Code', f.split('Code', '\\*').alias('Codes'))
maxCodes = df1.agg(f.max(f.size('Codes'))).first()[0]      # 3
df1.select(
  'ID', 'Code', 
  *[f.col('Codes').getItem(i).alias(f'Code{i+1}') for i in range(maxCodes)]
).show()
+---+-----------------+-----+-----+-----+
| ID|             Code|Code1|Code2|Code3|
+---+-----------------+-----+-----+-----+
| 10|      A1005*B1003|A1005|B1003| null|
| 12|A1007*D1008*C1004|A1007|D1008|C1004|
+---+-----------------+-----+-----+-----+
```

Comment: Hi ,
Thank you for the quick reply.

The code column holds the arithmetic operators. The code column can store values like 
(A1002*B1002)-C1003+D1005 or A1004/(C1008-D1006). And the number of codes in the string can go upto 7.

Comment: If the word you want to extract contains only digits and letters, you can replace `f.split(...)` in above two options with `f.array_remove(f.split('Code', '\\W+'), '')`, and it should give the result you needed.

Comment: Hi, 

Could you please help me with transpose the same dataset as below.

ID     Code                                             Code_T
10     A1005*B1003                               A1005
10     A1005*B1003                               B1003
12     A1007*D1008*C1004                   A1007
12     A1007*D1008*C1004                   D1008
12     A1007*D1008*C1004                   C1004