# split a string column on the plus sign (+) in spark and trim the result

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to generate a column based on the value of an existing column. Where ever there is plus sign we want to split and pickup the 2nd part of the column and trim if there is any space.

```python
df = spark.sql("select '10/35/70/25% T4Max-300 + 20/45/80/25% T4Max-400' as col1")
df1 = df.withColumn("newcol",col('col1').split("+")[1].strip())
```

getting the error `TypeError: 'Column' object is not callable`

Expected output is `20/45/80/25% T4Max-400`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Split Spark Dataframe string column into multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39235704/split-spark-dataframe-string-column-into-multiple-columns)

Comment: `split` and `trim` are not a methods of `Column` - you need to call `pyspark.sql.functions.split/trim` and pass in the column. See the linked duplicate for details.

Answer (score 0):

The code `col('col1')` returns the [`pyspark.sql.Column`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.Column) in your DataFrame with the name `"col1"`.

You are getting the error:

> ```python
> TypeError: 'Column' object is not callable
> ```

because you are trying to call `split` (and `trim`) as methods on this column, but no such methods exist.

Instead you want to call the functions [`pyspark.sql.functions.split()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.split) and [`pyspark.sql.functions.trim()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.trim) with the `Column` passed in as an argument.

For instance:

```python
df1 = df.withColumn(
    "newcol",
    f.trim(
        f.split(f.col('col1'), r"\+")[1]
    )
)
df1.show(truncate=False)
#+-----------------------------------------------+----------------------+
#|col1                                           |newcol                |
#+-----------------------------------------------+----------------------+
#|10/35/70/25% T4Max-300 + 20/45/80/25% T4Max-400|20/45/80/25% T4Max-400|
#+-----------------------------------------------+----------------------+
```

The second argument to `split()` is treated as a regular expression pattern, so the `+` has to be escaped.