# Python Spark SubString in Dataframe

Tags: python, azure-databricks

Given the following..

```
df.show()

+--------------+
|          name|
+--------------+
| Some_Cool_Guy|
|Some_Other_Guy|
+--------------+
```

how do i pick out the 'middle' part of the string correctly?? Am i missing a library??

i've tried:

```
df.withColumn("newCol", df["name"]).show()

+--------------+--------------+
|          name|        newCol|
+--------------+--------------+
| Some_Cool_Guy| Some_Cool_Guy|
|Some_Other_Guy|Some_Other_Guy|
+--------------+--------------+
```

and then a bit of string manipulation..

```
df.withColumn("newCol", df["name"].split('_')[1]).show()
```

but this just blows up with..

```
'Column' object is not callable.
```

The expected out come is..

```
+--------------+------+
|          name|newCol|
+--------------+------+
| Some_Cool_Guy|  Cool|
|Some_Other_Guy| Other|
+--------------+------+
```

this is driving me a bit round the bend..

cheers!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Split Spark Dataframe string column into multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39235704/split-spark-dataframe-string-column-into-multiple-columns)

Comment: Looks it, thanks! 