# extract tags from Dataframe column

Tags: python, azure, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I have a dataframe with data from Azure Consumtion Databricks python notebook. I am showing here just subset of cols/rows.

```
[Row(ResourceRate='0.029995920244854', PreTaxCost='0.719902085876484',  
ResourceType='Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines',  Tags=None, ),
 Row(ResourceRate='1.10999258782982',  PreTaxCost='26.6398221079157',  
ResourceType='Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines',  
Tags='"{  ""project"": ""70023"",  ""service"": ""10043""}"')
 ]
```

I need to extract tags from Tags column and expose them as (table) columns.
Btw, I am not sure where do I get these pairs of double quotes. Probably from source table beeing .csv. But that is probably, easy to resolve at the end.

I use pyspark. I was trying to do something like this [Split Spark Dataframe string column into multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39235704/split-spark-dataframe-string-column-into-multiple-columns)

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import monotonically_increasing_id
from pyspark.sql.functions import split, posexplode, concat, expr, lit, col, first
df2 = df.withColumn("num", monotonically_increasing_id())
df3 = df2.select(
        "num",
        split("Tags", ", ").alias("Tags"),
        posexplode(split("Tags", ",")).alias("pos", "val")
    )
#display(df3)
df4 = df3.drop("val")\
    .select(
        "num",
        concat(lit("Tag"),col("pos").cast("string")).alias("name"),
        expr("Tags[pos]").alias("val")
    )
# display(df4)
df5 = df4.groupBy("num").pivot("name").agg(first("val"))
display(df5)
```

That is not exactly what I want.

```
num     Tag0
964     
1677    """project"": ""70023"", """service"": ""10024""
2040    """project"": ""70025"", """service"": ""10034""
2214    
...
```

I would prefer to get tags as cols:

```
num     project        service       ResourceRate       PreTaxCost
964                                  0.029995920244854  0.719902085876484
677     70023          10024         1.10999258782982   26.6398221079157
2040    70025          10034         0.029995920244854  0.719902085876484
2214                                 0.029995920244854  0.719902085876484
...
```

Comment: [Row(ResourceRate='0.029995920244854', PreTaxCost='0.719902085876484', ResourceType='Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines',   
Tags=None, ),  
 Row(ResourceRate='1.10999258782982',  PreTaxCost='26.6398221079157',  ResourceType='Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines',   
 Tags='"{  ""project"": ""70023"",  ""service"": ""10043""}"')
 ]

Comment: Can u show the structure of DF?

Comment: Whole structure is very long and flat - just bunch of strings. Important one is Tags. It can contain other (interesting) values.

Comment: I could do just splitting of a field and leave u to do the rest.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you can convert `Tags` to a column of JSON strings (*[trim](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/sql/index.html#trim)* the leading and trailing `"` and *[regexp_replace](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/sql/index.html#regexp_replace)* double `"` to a lone `"`) and then use *[json_tuple()](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.json_tuple)* to retrieve the desired fields. see below code:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import expr, json_tuple

df.withColumn('Tags', expr("""regexp_replace(trim(BOTH '"' FROM Tags), '""', '"')""")) \
  .select('*', json_tuple('Tags', 'project', 'service').alias('project','service'))\
  .show()                                                  
#+-----------------+-----------------+--------------------+--------------------+-------+-------+
#|       PreTaxCost|     ResourceRate|        ResourceType|                Tags|project|service|
#+-----------------+-----------------+--------------------+--------------------+-------+-------+
#|0.719902085876484|0.029995920244854|Microsoft.Compute...|                null|   null|   null|
#| 26.6398221079157| 1.10999258782982|Microsoft.Compute...|{ "project": "700...|  70023|  10043|
#+-----------------+-----------------+--------------------+--------------------+-------+-------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is sample code trying to split tags into multiple columns :

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import pyspark.sql.functions as f


def columnList(r):
  val = str(r[0].tags)
  i = int(val.index("{") + 1)
  j = int(val.index("}"))
  val = val[i:j]
  vals = val.split(",")
  collist = []
  collist.append('id')
  for val in vals:
    keyval = val.split(":")
    key = keyval[0]
    collist.append(key.replace('"',""))
  return collist

def valueList(r):
  val = r[1]
  i = int(val.index("{")+1)
  j = int(val.index("}"))
  val = val[i:j]
  vals = val.split(",")
  valList = []
  valList.append(r[0])
  for val in vals:
      keyval = val.split(":")
      value = keyval[1]
      valList.append(value.replace('"',""))
  return valList

sc = SparkSession.builder.appName("example").\
config("spark.driver.memory","1g").\
config("spark.executor.cores",2).\
config("spark.max.cores",4).getOrCreate()

df =
```

sc.read.format("csv").option("header","true").option("delimiter","|").load("columns.csv")

```
tagsdf = df.select("id","tags")


colList = columnList(tagsdf.rdd.take(1))
tagsdfrdd = tagsdf.rdd.map(lambda r : valueList(r))

dfwithnewcolumns = tagsdfrdd.toDF(colList)

newdf = df.drop("tags").join(dfwithnewcolumns,on=["id"])

newdf.show()
```

Sample test file
   id|ResourceRate|PreTaxCost|ResourceType|Tags
1|'1.10999258782982'|'26.6398221079157'|'Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines'|'"{  ""project"": ""70023"",  ""service"": ""10043""}"'

If you dont have id column then you may want to merge the rdds