# How to split a single Dataset column to multiple columns

Tags: java, apache-spark

How to split a single Dataset column to multiple columns  in spark. I found something in [pyspark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39235704/split-spark-dataframe-string-column-into-multiple-columns) and tried to implement the same approach in java,but how can i extend this to `n` columns without specifying any schema?

Dataset Loooks like this

```
    data                                                                                                                            |
    +--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
    |0311111111111111|00000005067242541501|18275008905683|86.80||DESC\|123|10000003|2|1145                                           |
    |0311111111111111|00000005067242541501|B8426621002A|500.00||DESC\|TRF |10000015|28|1170                                          |
    +--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

    Columns:

    id, tid, mid, amount, mname, desc, brand, brandId, mcc
```

**The desc column can contain `|` which is also field dilimiter.In the case where fields is having '|' can we wrap the field in double quotes?

Comment: please share the dataset that you are operating. Also the columns

Comment: As they explained there - if the number of items to split is constant, you can do it reasonably in multiple columns, but if each row has a different number of items, you should split into separate rows. Maybe a better approach is to tell us what you want to do with the items, so we can suggest a better dataset representation.

Comment: the number of columns can increase overtime but it will be same for all rows. also its possible that any of the columns can contain '|' which is also field delimiter

Comment: The answer there by user *pault* seems to be what you are looking for. The regex for the split can be a problem if you have escaped backslashes - you'll need to write a UDF for that, otherwise you can simply use a regex for "pipe not preceded by backslash". But the question is, why is the data like this? Why don't you load it split from whatever source you got it from?

Answer (score 0):

According to the java you have to make sure your dataset string value (variable str ) should like this because. In java Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are  \b  \t  \n  \f  \r  \"  \'  \ )
You can try like this way.

```
    String str =   "0311111111111111|00000005067242541501|18275008905683|86.80||DESC\\|123|10000003|2|1145";
    String str1 = str.substring(0, str.indexOf("\\"));
    String str2 = str.substring(str.indexOf("\\"));
    String [] splite1 = str1.split("\\|");
    String [] splite2 = str2.split("\\|");
    //for DESC column 
    String desc = splite1[splite1.length -1 ] + splite2[0] + "|" + splite2[1] ;
```