# Pyspark Split Dataframe string column into multiple columns

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

I'm performing an example of Spark Structure streaming on spark 3.0.0, for this, I'm using twitter data.
I've pushed twitter data in Kafka, single records it looks like this

> 2020-07-21 10:48:19|1265200268284588034|RT @narendramodi: Had an extensive interaction with CEO of @IBM, Mr. @ArvindKrishna. We discussed several subjects relating to technology,…|Hyderabad, India

Here every field is separated by '|' and the fields are

1. Date time
2. User ID
3. Tweet Text
4. Location

Now reading this message in Spark I got data frame like this

```
 key |   value 
-----+-------------------------
     |  2020-07-21 10:48:19|1265200268284588034|RT @narendramodi: Had an extensive interaction with CEO of @IBM, Mr. @ArvindKrishna. We discussed several subjects relating to technology,…|Hyderabad, India
```

And according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39235705/12927963) answer, I've add following block of code in my App.

```
split_col =  pyspark.sql.functions.split(df['value'], '|')


df = df.withColumn("Tweet Time", split_col.getItem(0))
df = df.withColumn("User ID", split_col.getItem(1))
df = df.withColumn("Tweet Text", split_col.getItem(2))
df = df.withColumn("Location", split_col.getItem(3))
df = df.drop("key")
```

but it's giving me output like this,

```
                            A                                                                                                                                                                         |  B   |   C     |   D    |  E  |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+---------+--------+-----+
  2020-07-21 10:48:19|1265200268284588034|RT @narendramodi: Had an extensive interaction with CEO of @IBM, Mr. @ArvindKrishna. We discussed several subjects relating to technology,…|Hyderabad, India|2     |    0    |    2   |  0  |
```

but I want output like this

```
       Tweet Time      |       User ID           |                            Tweet text                                                                                                        |   Location        |
-----------------------+-------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------+
  2020-07-21 10:48:19  |   1265200268284588034   |  RT @narendramodi: Had an extensive interaction with CEO of @IBM, Mr. @ArvindKrishna. We discussed several subjects relating to technology,… |  Hyderabad, India |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it accepts a ***pattern: a string representing a regular expression. The regex string should be
a Java regular expression.***

Use `"\\|"` to split by pipe or `'[|]'`

```
split_col =  split(df.value, '\\|',)

df = df.withColumn("Tweet Time", split_col.getItem(0))\
    .withColumn("User ID", split_col.getItem(1))\
    .withColumn("Tweet Text", split_col.getItem(2))\
    .withColumn("Location", split_col.getItem(3))\
    .drop("key")
```

Output:

```
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------+
|value                                                                                                                                                                                               |Tweet Time         |User ID            |Tweet Text                                                                                                                                 |Location        |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------+
|2020-07-21 10:48:19|1265200268284588034|RT @narendramodi: Had an extensive interaction with CEO of @IBM, Mr. @ArvindKrishna. We discussed several subjects relating to technology,…|Hyderabad, India|2020-07-21 10:48:19|1265200268284588034|RT @narendramodi: Had an extensive interaction with CEO of @IBM, Mr. @ArvindKrishna. We discussed several subjects relating to technology,…|Hyderabad, India|
|2020-07-21 10:48:19|1265200268284588034|RT @narendramodi: Had an extensive interaction with CEO of @IBM, Mr. @ArvindKrishna. We discussed several subjects relating to technology,…|Hyderabad, India|2020-07-21 10:48:19|1265200268284588034|RT @narendramodi: Had an extensive interaction with CEO of @IBM, Mr. @ArvindKrishna. We discussed several subjects relating to technology,…|Hyderabad, India|
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------+
```