# How to slice until the last item to form new columns?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe following format

```
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|value                                                                                            |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|datalake-performance/raw/bamboohr/bamboohr_custom_turnover_data/2020/12/10/11:15.csv             |
|datalake-performance/raw/gitlab/002429d9-908c-497b-96ba-67794b31f0cd                             |
|datalake-performance/processed/bamboohr/employee/04-08-2020/16:23.csv                            |
|datalake-performance/raw/zoom/user/year=2020/month=09/day=22/a329affc-b1f5-45d1-932a-fbb13d9873d6|
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I want to generate a new column with following format:

```
newcol
[bamboohr_custom_turnover_data, 2020, 12, 10]
[]
[employee, 04-08-2020]
[user, year=2020, month=09, day=22]
```

To do so with Pandas, looks like this

```
df['value'].str.split('/').str[3:-1]
```

I have tried the below with PySpark but I receive an error

```
df = df.withColumn("list", (split(col("value"), "/")))    
df.select(slice(df["list"], 3, size(df["list"]) - (3 + 1)))
```

> TypeError: Column is not iterable

How do I get the slice through `[3:-1]` in PySpark?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Spark SQL functions `slice` and `size` to achieve slicing. Note that Spark SQL array indices start from 1 instead of 0.

```
df2 = df.selectExpr("slice(split(value, '/'), 4, size(split(value, '/')) - 4) newcol")

df2.show(truncate=False)
+---------------------------------------------+
|newcol                                       |
+---------------------------------------------+
|[bamboohr_custom_turnover_data, 2020, 12, 10]|
|[]                                           |
|[employee, 04-08-2020]                       |
|[user, year=2020, month=09, day=22]          |
+---------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

`slice` function can also accept negative index `start` in order to start from the end. You want 4 parts and ignore the last one, so start from -5 and take 4:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, split, slice

df = df.withColumn("newcol", slice(split(col("value"), "/"), -5, 4)) 
df.select("newcol").show(truncate=False)

#+---------------------------------------------+
#|newcol                                       |
#+---------------------------------------------+
#|[bamboohr_custom_turnover_data, 2020, 12, 10]|
#|[]                                           |
#|[processed, bamboohr, employee, 04-08-2020]  |
#|[user, year=2020, month=09, day=22]          |
#+---------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this -

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df_updated = df.withColumn("new value",df.select(F.split(df.value,"/")).rdd.flatMap(
            lambda x: x[3:-1]))
```

Other references - [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39235704/split-spark-dataframe-string-column-into-multiple-columns)

Comment: Output from that, "AssertionError: col should be Column"