# Splitting a column on a dot separator

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, split, separator

How to split PySpark dataframe column with separator as dot (`.`). To me it doesn't seem to work when I use `split` used on a dot.

E.g. column with value `abcd.efgh`, should be split into two columns with values `abcd` and `efgh`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Split Spark Dataframe string column into multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39235704/split-spark-dataframe-string-column-into-multiple-columns)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is the `df` based on your example.

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession, functions as F
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

df = spark.createDataFrame([('abcd.efgh',)], ['c1'])
df.show()
#+---------+
#|       c1|
#+---------+
#|abcd.efgh|
#+---------+
```

For splitting one can use [`split`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.split.html#pyspark.sql.functions.split) like this:

```py
splitCol = F.split('c1', '[.]', 2)
df = df.select(
    splitCol[0].alias('c1_0'),
    splitCol[1].alias('c1_1'),
)
df.show()
#+----+----+
#|c1_0|c1_1|
#+----+----+
#|abcd|efgh|
#+----+----+
```