# How to split one column into 3 columns in python or PySpark

Tags: python, list, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have:

```
Customerkeycode
B01:B14:110083
```

I want:

```
PlanningCustomerSuperGroupCode, DPGCode, APGCode
BO1,                            B14,     110083
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Split Spark dataframe string column into multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39235704/split-spark-dataframe-string-column-into-multiple-columns)

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Customerkeycode": [
            "B01:B14:110083",
            "B02:B15:110084"
        ]
    }
)

df['PlanningCustomerSuperGroupCode'] = df['Customerkeycode'].apply(lambda x: x.split(":")[0])
df['DPGCode'] = df['Customerkeycode'].apply(lambda x: x.split(":")[1])
df['APGCode'] = df['Customerkeycode'].apply(lambda x: x.split(":")[2])

df_rep = df.drop("Customerkeycode", axis = 1)

print(df_rep)

   PlanningCustomerSuperGroupCode DPGCode APGCode
0                            B01     B14  110083
1                            B02     B15  110084
```

Comment: hi ashish jain   i dont required Customerkeycode becase it is source column

Comment: Please check the code now.

Answer (score 0):

In pyspark, first `split` the string into an array, and then use the `getItem` method to split it into multiple columns.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

...
cols = ['PlanningCustomerSuperGroupCode', 'DPGCode', 'APGCode']
arr_cols = [F.split('Customerkeycode', ':').getItem(i).alias(cols[i]) for i in range(3)]
df = df.select(*arr_cols)
df.show(truncate=False)
```

Comment: Instead of `.getItem(i)` you could probably do `[i]`

Answer (score 0):

split into 3 columns by the ':' with column names ['PlanningCustomerSuperGroupCode', 'DPGCode', 'APGCode']

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df.withColumn('PlanningCustomerSuperGroupCode', F.split(F.col('Customerkeycode'), ':')[0]) \
    .withColumn('DPGCode', F.split(F.col('Customerkeycode'), ':')[1]) \
    .withColumn('APGCode', F.split(F.col('Customerkeycode'), ':')[2]) \
    .drop('Customerkeycode') \
    .show()
```